# How can we improve the quality of questions like this?

Tags: discussion

It is unfortunate that [questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858077/dynamically-adding-devexpress-gridcontrol-to-c-sharp-windows-application) were allowed to stay open (and got 5 UVs). It's great that someone received an answer ...but if that question had been asked today, it would have been railed to the coffin if the OP hadn't supplied evidence of previous attempts for resolution.

What is most damaging is the precedent ...if a new user comes along and sees this question, that person will believe that someone will write their entire solution. The notion of *show me teh codez* is not acceptable.

Asking for a way to increase the awareness of unacceptable questions is futile. I simply do not feel there is anything more we can reasonably accomplish. We have a good team of moderators, editors and reviewers.

But to the problem of questions like this that *slipped through the cracks*, how can we improve it's quality? Should it be closed? Locked with an explanation?

Comment: Just vote to close it, same as you would today. Downvote, too, if you feel it's appropriate.

Comment: It needed editing, so I did that.  It's not the greatest question, but it got a good answer.

Comment: +1.  You have a good point - it's a corner case where many people find it very *useful* even though the OP took no part in that.

Comment: @CodyGray close no, DV yes.  "Shows no research effort" but is a very clear, constructive and evidently useful question.

Comment: +1 for the self-referential question title (although probably unintended!).

Answer (score 5):

Huh... That question's had 21 thousand views. I'm not sure you can say it "fell through the cracks", given the average view count for questions asked in '09 is 2.8K.

In addition to the up-votes, 8 anonymous users have marked it helpful (one marked it unhelpful), with the answer getting 6 and 3 helpful/unhelpful anonymous votes respectively.

That's not a lot of feedback, particularly given the number of views. If it really bugs you, you could down-vote it and reduce the score by 20%. Think about that.

Or don't. The guy asked a simple question, got a simple answer that satisfied him, and long ago moved on. Who cares?

Comment: I'll agree it has good stats. The point is that the question, if asked today, would have been closed in 5 minutes. It also sets the example that this is an okay question to ask and sets a new user up for failure.

Comment: You mean like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755158/how-do-i-tell-which-control-the-mouse-has-been-clicked-over)? Not *all* "howto" questions get closed, @IAbstract. Some of them even get decent answers. After all this time, there's still no "didn't post wall of code" close reason. As much as lazy questions bug me, I'd be more concerned if specific questions with specific answers were getting closed just for the hell of it; there's nothing necessarily wrong with a simple question.

Comment: If we're going to add a "wall of code" close reason, let's start with "*did* post a wall of code".

Comment: @Shog9: I don't understand why you think I expect a wall of code. The expectation is that we simply see some effort. Granted, not all questions require code. But the question I pointed out is nothing more than *show me the code*.